# Trying to open and read a file in python but it creates and opens an empty file

Tags: python, file, csv

I am trying to open several csv files in python using this code:

```
file= open('file.csv', "r")

contents= file.read()
allLines = file.readlines()
print(contents)
print(allLines)
```

But all python prints is "[]"

When I look in the folder for my python project- the file is there but it is now empty- what's going wrong?

Comment: Your title is misleading, you're not creating a file here, just reading...

Comment: Is the file you are opening in the same directory as the file?

Comment: Since the file is now empty: are you sure you haven't opened the file in write mode before? `open('file.csv', 'w')`

Comment: The file had to be empty before interacting with it using the code above.  There's no way this code wrote over it.

Comment: Have you tried creating the file again? This code is not writing to your file, so it cannot make it empty...

Comment: Thanks for answering! So the file I want to open is on a file on the desktop like the python project..

Comment: The original file has data in it but the python project seems to have copied it and placed an empty one in the same directory as the project

Comment: If your file is not on the project directory then what Python will do is to create an empty one. If you want to open the one on the desktop you need to specify the full path.

Comment: Ahhh okay- thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With regards to why python is printing an empty array, I'm assuming that you only experience this when printing `allLines` . When using read operations on file that you've left open, Python leaves the read cursor at the end of the file. I believe if you use `seek(0)` you can return the read cursor back to the beginning of the file. i.e.:

```
file = open('file.csv', 'r')
contents = file.read()
file.seek(0)
allLines = file.readlines()
print(contents)
print(allLines)
```

Comment: It should only be seen as a workaround, because dist io are normally much more expensive than memory accesses. So unless you do that in order not to load the full file in memory, you should try to read only once from disk.

Answer (score 0):

This seems rather unusual that it would be removing your data since it is only reading. You shold try providing the full path to the file.